# Signing Firmware

Tags: device-firmware, open-source

I have successfully created my own custom firmware and loaded it onto a phone. But I was wondering why I didn't need to sign the firmware before loading it, or was it signed with a debug key similar to when you test your own android app?

Comment: Did you install it to on the phone with a custom recovery menu? They often have the signature check disabled by default, so that could be a possibility.

Comment: I installed it on a Nexus one and just loaded my images through the bootloader

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK the N1 doesn't require signed firmware, at least not once you unlock the bootloader -- it's a dev phone.  [Unofficial confirmation](http://noswap.com/blog/android-is-open/):

> I specifically purchased a Nexus One because it supports the ability to flash the phone with unsigned firmware.

Comment: What about other phones?

Comment: @Hank It's possible with some, but not all.  The Galaxy S can have a custom recovery installed once you've rooted it, for example, and naturally the custom recovery doesn't check to see if the firmware's signed.